# How can i set a time limit to a page link in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Asp.net and I would like to know I can set a time and date to a page link to expire?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give us much context in your question, so I'm going to reply assuming some things: You're using ASP.NET MVC and the URL is something like www.something.com/asdf?token=abc

As you're new, I urge you to be more specific when asking, though.

You should be able to do so using the controller to establish the criteria to say whether or not the page has expired.

In the controller for Asdf, check if token "abc" is still valid or not (can't be more specific here, because I lack the details of your problem). If it is, render the page as usual. If it's not, redirect to an error page.